Ansible check if service is running
I have a need to execute things in Ansible 2.9 task based on a fact if service is started or not.
This is the code I use

- name: 'Check status of phpfpm-www56 service'
  command: 'systemctl is-active --quiet php5.6-fpm'
  register: cmd_fpm56_status

- name: 'Some task'
  command: 'somescript'
  when: cmd_fpm56_status.rc == 0


When I run ansible lint on this I get following error message:
command-instead-of-module: systemctl used in place of systemd module
no-changed-when: Commands should not change things if nothing needs doing
Is there a way to use systemd module to just "ask" state of the service?

Service Facts Module

You can use the service facts module to get the state of all services. I realize that is more than you need but you can still reference the service you want to check.
---
- name: Checking Service Status
  hosts: "{{ hostgroup }}"
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

    - name: Populate service facts
      service_facts:

    - name: Print Service state
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: ansible_facts.services['php-fpm.service'].state

Which would give you an output like this.
TASK [Print Service state] *********************************
ok: [mywebserver] =>
  ansible_facts.services['php-fpm.service'].state: running


You can use service_facts module.
example playbook:
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local



  tasks:
  - name: Gather services facts
    ansible.builtin.service_facts:

  - name: Print status of ssh service
    debug:
      msg: |-
        ssh state is {{ services['ssh.service'].state }}

  - name: enable nginx service if it's not
    become: true
    ansible.builtin.systemd:
      enabled: false
      name: nginx
    when: services['nginx.service'].status != "enabled"


PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] 

*************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Gather services facts] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Print status of ssh service] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "ssh state is running"
}

TASK [enable nginx service if it's not] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0


Thanks to the @Squashman comment I figured it out. Updated code looks like this:

- name: 'Service facts'
  service_facts:

- name: 'Some task'
  command: 'somescript'
  when:
    - services is defined
    - "'php5.6-fpm.service' in services"
    - services['php5.6-fpm.service'].state == 'running'



You don't need to register the service facts.

I added check_mode because I do not wish to actually update global ansible facts just get actual snapshot and operate on it directly

OK, after some more testing I understand that registering has no sense. Updated code to reflect that
